# How do you make a rectangle and triangle shape in C++

Tags: c++

How do i achieve this format when i keyed in int of  ' 245 ':

(where if it is odd number it will be a rectangle, and even number will be triangle)

```
 1
 1 2

 1 
 1 2
 1 2 3
 1 2 3 4

 1 2 3 4 5
 1 2 3 4 5
 1 2 3 4 5
 1 2 3 4 5
 1 2 3 4 5
```

This is my code so far:

(I can't seemed to output triangle and rectangle at the same time)

```
int n;
int lastDigit;

do
{
    cout << "Enter a positive integer: ";
    cin >> n;

}while ( n <= 1 || n == '0');

cout << endl;

// If even digit - tri
do
{
    lastDigit = n%10;

    if (lastDigit / 2 ==0)
    {
        for (int i = 1; i <= lastDigit; ++i)
            for (int tri = 1; tri <= i; ++tri)
                cout << "\t" << tri;

        cout << endl;
    }

    // if odd digit - rect
    else if (lastDigit / 2 != 0)
    {
        for (int i = 1; i <= lastDigit; i++)
        {
            for (int rect = 1; rect <= i; rect++)
                cout << "\t" << rect;

            cout << endl;
        }
        n = n/10;
    }

    cout << endl;

}while (lastDigit != 0);

n = n/10;
cout << endl;

return 0;
```

And, how should i code when keyed in the int, the compiler will extract the first digit (From left to right) and output it accordingly?

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: btw `n == '0'` compares `n` with the *character* 0, which is, in general, not-zero (in fact does C++ allow for an *encoding* where '0' is zero? ).

Comment: You should not use normal division to check if a digit is even or not. Instead use the *modulo* operator `%`.  If you think a little while, lets say that the last digit is `8` then dividing it by `2` will result in `4` and not zero. Then you don't need to extract the last digit either, but can use modulo on the full number. You also don't need `else if` for that check.

Comment: Please format your code correctly. Especially indentations help us understand what you are doing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following is the complete code.

**Step1**: Take user input and check whether it's odd or even.

**Step2**: If it is odd then perform triangle else rectangle.

```
#include<iostream>
int main () {

int n;

cout<<"Enter number: ";
cin>>n;

if (n % 2 != 0)
{
    for(int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
    {
        cout<<endl;
        for(int j = 1; j <= n; j++)
        {
            cout<<j<<" ";
        }
    }
}
else
{
    for(int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
    {
        cout<<endl;
        for(int j = 1; j <= i; j++)
        {
            cout<<j<<" ";
        }
    }
}

return 0; 
}
```

Comment: Hi saif, when i followed using your code, I got a never ending loop.

Comment: It seemed that, whenever, I changed it to %, i get a never ending loop, where numbers just popped out continuously.

Comment: there is no need to change %, % is used for recognizing even/odd numbers

Comment: just copy and paste then run it give input. Ex: n is 5 output will be:

1 2 3 4 5
1 2 3 4 5
1 2 3 4 5
1 2 3 4 5
1 2 3 4 5

Comment: after this line #include<iostream>, write "using namespace std".

Comment: you forgot using namespace std;

Comment: yes, add using namespace std; then this will work perfectly

Answer (score 0):

Both of your print is similar. I suggest:

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

int main () {

    int n;

    cout << "Enter number: ";
    cin >> n;

    int i = 1;
    int& rowLim = ((n % 2) ? n : i);

    for(i = 1; i <= n; i++)
    {
        cout << endl;
        for(int j = 1; j <= rowLim; j++)
        {
            cout<<j<<" ";
        }
    }

    return 0; 

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simplest would be to use a `string`, iterate `char` by `char` and output accordingly. For instance

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    string s;
    cin >> s;
    for (char c : s) {
        int n = c - '0';
        bool k = n % 2;
        for (int i = 1; i <= n; ++i) {
            for (int j = 1; j <= (k ? n : i); ++j)
                cout << " " << j;
            cout << endl;
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
    return 0; 
}
```

**Output**

```
 1
 1 2

 1
 1 2
 1 2 3
 1 2 3 4

 1 2 3 4 5
 1 2 3 4 5
 1 2 3 4 5
 1 2 3 4 5
 1 2 3 4 5
```

See a [<kbd>DEMO</kbd>](http://ideone.com/NWaRE9)